# Spring REST not getting files from MultiPartHttpServletRequest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, multipartform-data

I am attempting to upload files via Angular 1.5 to a Spring REST endpoint.

I'm not getting any errors, because the `multiPartRequest.getFileNames();` is returning null. However my JS POST seems to be passing through the request correctly.

However, I can't seem to work it out. I have been staring it for hours now and need someone to point out the obvious thing I have missed.

Any help, suggestions are appreciated.

POST Request example:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:50188
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryIPlVKLnf1ZIQNPHV
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:49693
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:49693/test.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryIPlVKLnf1ZIQNPHV
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="post-image1.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryIPlVKLnf1ZIQNPHV--
Name
```

I am using the below HTML

```
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data">                     
                        <input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().upload(this.files)"/>
                        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
                        <li ng-repeat="file in files">{{file.name}}</li>
                </form>
```

With the follwing JS

```
$scope.upload = function(files) {
            var fd = new FormData();
            //Take the first selected file
            fd.append("file", files[0]);

            $http.post('uploadURL', fd, {
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
                transformRequest: angular.identity
            })
             .success(function(d) {
                     console.log("Upload complete" +d);
            })

        };
```

And the the following REST Endpoint

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String upload (HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {

        MultipartHttpServletRequest multiPartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;

        Iterator<String> it = multiPartRequest.getFileNames();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            MultipartFile multiPartFile = multiPartRequest.getFile(it.next());

            String filename = multiPartFile.getOriginalFilename();
            imageName = filename;

            String path = new File("src/main/resources/images").getAbsolutePath() + "/" + filename;

            try {
                multiPartFile.transferTo(new File(path));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: The path is not available, change the path like `C:\\images`.

Comment: @RomanC it doesn't get that far as the iterator is null because the multiPartRequest.getFiles returns an empty list.

Comment: Really in fact no files are uploaded.

Comment: @RomanC Yes, that's the point. The files are being uploaded according to the browser. However the REST requesting isn't seeing them.

Answer (score 2):

Try to make it so

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

i have the same problem, i solve it by change the `<button type="submit">Upload</button>` to `<input type="submit">`